# How to search and replace a number starting with 0?

Tags: search, editing

I know how to do a normal search and replace ,but say for instance that I want to replace all numbers in a buffer that starts with a 0 and the second number is a generic number, how do I match that pattern?

Say that I want to remove all numbers that begins with a zero followed by some other number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can remove all numbers starting with `0` using `query-replace-regexp`.

1. `C-M-%` (default binding for `query-replace-regexp`)
2. `\b0[0-9]+ RET`*
3. `RET`
4. Now each `SPACE` key hit will replace one match (Hit `!` to replace all matches). **Hit `?` to learn about more `query-replace` bindings.**

* **Learn more about the elisp regular expressions from the [Regular Expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regular-Expressions.html) section in Emacs manual.**